# Who do we see packing Gwendolyn's clothes?

Tags: mouse-guard

In the *Mouse Guard* book, [*Winter 1152*](https://www.mouseguard.net/book/winter-1152/) we see a mouse with a Red cloak packing Gwendolyn's clothes or possibly armour away. I couldn't tell if this was Saxon, or Gwendolyn, and what significance this had? Has she resigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse you're referring to is Saxon. You can tell from the distinctive red cape, cape brooch and notched right ear.

[image: Saxon packing]

The note Gwendolyn's left (along with her silver 'dress armour') clearly states that she hasn't left the guard, just that she's going to go for a bit of a walkabout, ostensibly to choose a successor but really just to see some more of the world. In the very final scene we see Liaem walking away from the castle with Celanwés "Black Axe".

> "I did not know that my life with the Guard was missing anything **until
>   a red-cloaked mouse needed assurance** that there was more to life than
>   "this". While I have no plans to leave the Guards or my post, this
>   awakening between us has me choosing a successor for when the time
>   comes. The longest and darkest of nights came early this year
>   therefore every day henceforth becomes that much lighter - Gwendolyn"